# Working with JSON inside C# winmd

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I'm creating a winmd file for use in Windows 8 development. I want to have a great JavaScript (WinJS) experience but can't work out how to have my methods except raw JSON, for example I would like developers to code like this in WinJS:

```
bar.foo({ bar: 19 })
```

And inside my C# library I would have something like this

```
public sealed class Bar
{
    public void Foo(JsonObject jsonObject)
    {
```

This compiles but when I try to call foo from WinJS I get an error saying the signature of the method is invalid. I'm assuming this is because it exposes a 'managed' type Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject.

Any ideas how I can work with JSON passed from the WinJS world into .NET (within a WinMD).

Comment: JSON code is actually string based.  So it might be as simple as saying:  bar.foo(new JsonObject("{bar: 19}"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible, at least in the Developer Preview.

I created a C# method that has an `object` parameter with the assumption that any object that can be converted from JS form to .Net form through WinRT will be able to go through.

And it works for arrays: a JS array will be passed in as `object[]`. But if I try to pass a JSON object, a “Type mismatch” error is thrown. This is why I think it's not possible.

I also tried object created using [the `WinJS.Class.define()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229813.aspx), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a year old, but for anyone else encountering the same issue...

This can be done, but you need to make your winmd method signature takes in a string as a parameter and then use the static JsonObject.Parse parse the JSON text.

```
public sealed class Bar
{
    public void Foo(string json)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            var jobj = JsonObject.Parse(json);
            var barVal = jobj.GetNamedNumber("bar");
            // if all went well, barVal should be a double value of 
            // the number passed in the object (19.0 based on the original question).
        }                 
    }
}
```

When you call this method, though, you need to wrap the object definition in quotes to make it a string. You also need to wrap the field names in quotes or JsonObject.Parse will throw an exception saying the string is not a valid JSON string.

```
bar.foo("{ \"bar\": 19 }");
```

For an object with a lot of fields, this could be time consuming and result in ugly code.  Your better bet is to call JSON.stringify on the object to convert it to a string.

```
bar.foo(JSON.stringify({ bar: 19 }));
```

Or you could, of course, make some wrapper method that call JSON.stringify for you. Whatever works best for your situatiuon.

Answer (score -1):

I'm starting up on Windows 8 also and struggled much of the morning with parsing JSON.  [This link](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/09/21/Windows-8-applications-and-JSON-data.aspx) got me to the point where I could deserialize my JSON string into a Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject.

Here's the code I wound up with:

```
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.SendAsync(RequestMessage);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string json = response.Content.ReadAsString();
        ResponseObject = new JsonObject(json);
```

If you want to deserialize into your own data types, you could try System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.  I didn't have a lot of luck with that; I kept getting back null from the ReadObject() method and didn't see a way to get any diagnostic information.

Comment: Sorry...misread your question.  This works for the C# end of things but doesn't address WinJS.  The original comment on your question though seems like a possible way forward; have you tried creating a JsonObject from a string in WinJS and passing that into your foo() method?